# How do I handle consecutive multiple try's in swift 2.0

Tags: nested, try-catch, swift2

I have a block of code that needs to execute 2 statements that require a try.  Is it better to nest the try's and each one has their own do { } catch {}

```
 do { 
     try thingOne()
     do {
         try thingTwo()
     } catch let error as NSError {
          //handle this specific error
     }
 } catch let error as NSError {
      //handle the other specific error here
 }
```

...or wrap the try's in one do block and run them consecutively?

```
do {

   try thingOne()
   try thingTwo()
} catch let error as NSError {
    //do something with this error
}
```

The second scenario seems easier to read than the first, although will that `catch` work if either of those throws an error?

I would then need to distinguish between the different errors that get thrown, unless the errors are generic enough, then it might not matter.  Looked through the Apple documentation and didn't see anything regarding this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think second way is better

Suppose I have these two function

```
 func thingOne() throws{
      print("Thing 1")
      throw CustomError.Type1
}
func thingTwo() throws{
    print("Thing 2")

    throw CustomError.Type2

}
enum CustomError:ErrorType{
    case Type1
    case Type2
}
```

Then I will call it like this

```
   do {
        try thingOne()
        try thingTwo()
    } catch CustomError.Type1 {
        print("Error1")
    } catch CustomError.Type2{
        print("Error2")
    } catch {
        print("Not known\(error) ")
    }
```

This will log

```
Thing 1
Error1
```

If `thingOne()` does not throws the error,it will log

```
Thing 1
Thing 2
Error2
```